# Knowing the position of a body when aplying impulse in Andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

Is it posible to know where a body will go **before** applying impulse. To my understanding i belive it is imposible after colision cause there is some randomness. But while is hasnt happened yet. How do i know where the body will go after x seconds?.
Thanks

I tryed with this formula based on my physics understanding but it doesnt work

```
private Vector2 getPlace(Vector2 force,float mass,float mTime){
    float time=mTime;
    Vector2 velocity=new Vector2(force.x/mass,force.y/mass);
    float xPosition=(float)((mWorld.getGravity().x/2)*(Math.pow(time,2))+time*((velocity.x+b.getLinearVelocity().x)));
    float yPosition=(float) ((mWorld.getGravity().y/2)*(Math.pow(time,2))+time*((velocity.y+b.getLinearVelocity().y)));
    Vector2 place=new Vector2(xPosition,yPosition);
    return place;
}
```

*Where b is the body*

if im right

(a * t^2)/2   + t * v    + iP  =  P

*Where a is aceleration, t is TIME, v velocity, iP initial position and P the final positon*

Comment: So impulse will be caused by collision? In the mean time look into this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32995/show-path-of-a-body-of-where-it-should-go-after-linear-impulse-is-applied

Comment: After seeing that, i belive that the formula will be the simpler. However i dont know what extra constant etc should i put to get the position.